# How to smoothly scroll content in an AIR Android Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have written a small class to be used to scroll content on mobile devices. The class works fine but the scrolling doesn't feel smooth. Here is the class:

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

public class FlickScroll extends Sprite {

    private var currentY:Number;
    private var lastY:Number;
    private var vy:Number;
    public var clickable:Boolean = true;
    private var dragging:Boolean = false;
    private var firstY:Number;
    private var secondY:Number;
    private var content:InteractiveObject;
    private var masker:InteractiveObject;
    private var topBounds:Number;
    private var bottomBounds:Number;
    private var Offset:Number;
    public var friction:Number = .90;
    public var flickable:Boolean = false;
    public var scrollVelocity:Number;

    public function FlickScroll(Masker:InteractiveObject, Content:InteractiveObject, TopBounds:Number, BottomBounds:Number) {
        masker = Masker;
        content = Content;
        topBounds = TopBounds;
        bottomBounds = BottomBounds;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage, false, 0, true);
    }
    private function onAddedToStage(evt:Event):void
    {
        init();
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop, false, 0, true);

        content.mask = masker;
        content.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    }
    private function init():void
    {
        currentY = content.y;
        lastY = content.y;
        vy = 0;
        scrollVelocity = 2;
        content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onContentDown, false, 0, true);
    }
    private function onContentDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {

        firstY = content.y;
        Offset = content.mouseY;
        trace(mouseY, Offset, mouseY - Offset);

        content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onContentMove, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onContentUp, false, 0, true);
    }
    private function onContentMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {

        dragging = true;
        clickable = false;
        content.y = mouseY - Offset;


        if(content.y > topBounds + 200)
        {
            content.y = topBounds + 200;
        }
        else if(content.y < bottomBounds - 200)
        {
            content.y = bottomBounds - 200;
        }



        trace("ContentY: ", content.y, "Bottom Bounds: ", bottomBounds, "Top Bounds: ", topBounds);

        evt.updateAfterEvent();
    }
    private function onContentUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        secondY = content.y;
        var dy:Number = secondY - firstY;

        if(dy < 20 && dy > -20)
        {
            clickable = true;
        }

        if(content.y > this.topBounds)
        {
            TweenMax.to(content, .4, {y:topBounds, ease:Expo.easeOut});
        }
        else if( content.y < this.bottomBounds)
        {
            TweenMax.to(content, .4, {y:bottomBounds, ease:Expo.easeOut});
        }
        else
        {
            dragging = false;
        }
        //setTimeout(setDraggingFalse, 400);


        content.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onContentMove);
        content.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onContentUp);
    }
    private function onLoop(evt:Event):void
    {
        if(this.flickable)
        {

            if(dragging)
            {
                lastY = currentY;
                currentY = mouseY;
                vy = (currentY - lastY)/scrollVelocity;
            }
            else
            {
                content.y += vy;
                vy *= friction;
            }
        }

        if(!dragging)
        {
            if(content.y > topBounds)
            {
                content.y = topBounds;
            }
            else if(content.y < bottomBounds)
            {
                content.y = bottomBounds;
            }
        }
    }
    public function updateBounds(top:Number, bottom:Number):void
    {
        bottomBounds = bottom;
        topBounds = top;
    }

    private function setDraggingFalse():void
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

}
```

}

Sorry for the code being really messy. 
What steps can I take to make the scrolling feel more smooth? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, it's important to clarify what "NOT smooth" really means to you.   Does that mean jaggy or jerky movement? (like really bad anti-aliasing)  Or does it mean your frame rate is dropping (or too low to begin with) causing it to seemingly pause momentarily at random times?  Or does it mean that you want smooth and ease the movement instead of matching exactly the mouse position?   Please update your question to try and clarify problem more.   If you know how,  test that your framerate isn't dropping.  If you don't know how, I or someone can explain the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If youre using bitmaps, try following [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d62.html) guide. It deals with smoothly scrolling with bitmaps.

If youre dealing with a movieclip, startDrag() and stopDrag() aren't too bad. Maybe adding a Tween and decelerating it based on a frame by frame comparison of the mouses last y and current y to get the "thrust" on release of the mouse. Might have to lock the x position of the movieclip on a mouse move event (or y depending how how you want it to scroll).